# javascript addition and subtraction behaving weird

Tags: javascript, javascript-framework

When I tried to execute this piece of code, its giving me a very weird answer

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  a = 17.98 + 7.99 - 17.98 - 7.99 + 0 - 0;
  alert(a);
</script>
```

It should actually give me a zero. But instead it gives me an exponential value.
Can some one please help me with the answer.

Comment: you can read more about this here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1458633/elegant-workaround-for-javascript-floating-point-number-problem

Answer (score 2):

You should get -1.7763568394002505e-15. This represents -1.7763568394002505 * 10^(-15). This is a value very close to zero ; but the fact that you don't get zero is due to a rounding error. This is *normal behaviour*.

If you really want to know the in and outs, you can find out more at http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html

Comment: I solved the issue like this:

 <script type="text/javascript">
 a = 17.98 + 7.99 + 0;
 a+= (-17.98 - 7.99 - 0);
 alert(a);
    </script>
This gives me exactly zero. Thanks everyone for the reply.

Comment: Why would you like to have exactly zero ? You have to make your mind that computers will always give you approximated results, or prepare for headaches. Be glad to have -1.7763568394002505e-15 already !

Answer (score 1):

That's normal behaviour for floating point calculations.

There is only a limited number of values that can be represented exactly in the binary floating point format used, so most values are represented as the closest possible value.

A value like `7.99` might be represented as something like `7.98999999999997754`, so that's the value that you actually get when the code is parsed.

The difference between the actual value and the value that you expect is so small that it doesn't show up when you just display the value directly, as the value is rounded when it is turned back into a string format. When you do several calculations the small differences add up, and sooner or later you will see it.

The result that you get is `-0.0000000000000017763568394002505`, so that is very close to zero, but it's not exactly zero.

Answer (score 1):

Computers are not really good with handling floating points.

eg:
0.1 + 0.2 = 0.30000000000000004

> Because internally, computers use a format (binary floating-point)
>   that cannot accurately represent a number like 0.1, 0.2 or 0.3 at all.
>   When the code is compiled or interpreted, your “0.1” is already
>   rounded to the nearest number in that format, which results in a small
>   rounding error even before the calculation happens.

read more on : [What Every Programmer Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://floating-point-gui.de/)

Answer (score 0):

```
a = Math.ceil(17.98 + 7.99 - 17.98 - 7.99 + 0 - 0);
```

Comment: While that would give the rounded value, it does not explain _why_ this happens - which I believe to be the question.

Comment: explanations were already given before by many experts, this one is for _It should actually give me a zero._ part of the question since OP seems to want a rounded value

Comment: I solved the issue like this: <script type="text/javascript"> a = 17.98 + 7.99 + 0; a+= (-17.98 - 7.99 - 0); alert(a); </script> This gives me exactly zero. Thanks everyone for the reply.